# Node.JS on Solaris: Increase TCP's Initial Congestion Window to 10 segments (tcp slow-start)

Tags: performance, tcp, node.js, solaris

How can the [Initial Congestion Window be increased to 10](http://www.google.com/research/pubs/pub36640.html)? I read a suggestion that [it can be done with `TCP_INIT_CWND`](http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=456274), but I don't know how to do that.

I originally posted this to ServerFault because it seems appropriate, but Iain on ServerFault [suggested that it may a setting available to the application](https://serverfault.com/questions/244736/solaris-increase-tcps-initial-congestion-window-to-10-segments-tcp-slow-start/244928#244928) and that I may get a better answer here.

Comment: I recommend you stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and [#joyent](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=joyent&uio=d4) to see if they can help out. The joyent people know everything about Solaris.